# After 'group by', select value that is not null and from highest value in a specific column

Tags: sql, hana

I have a `TEST_RESULT` table that has one test result as a row.

```
version| test_id | test_result
---------------------------------------
v1     |   53    |     fail
v2     |   53    |     fail
v3     |   53    |     success
---------------------------------------
v1     |   60    |     unprocessable
v2     |   60    |     null
v3     |   60    |     null
```

Test `53` failed on v1, v2 but on `v3` it was patched and thus succeeded.
Test `60` was `unprocessable` in `v1`, and it was not executed in later versions `v2` and `v3`.

The final table I want to get out of this looks like this:

```
test_id | final_result
---------------------------------------
53      |   success
60      |   unprocessable
```

`final_result` would show **`test_result` value from the highest version IF the value is not null. If the value is null, it's going to show the next highest version's `test_result`** and so on. (Note that it would always have version row regardless of whether a version has test result or not).

I was able to give order to rows with the same `test_id` using `ROW_NUMBER()`, but a bit lost how'd we can implement 'non-null `test_result` value from version that is as high as possible` part. Is logic like this better to be implemented in backend code? I can't think of a suiting SQL operator for this.

```sql
SELECT
 test_id,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY test_Id ORDER BY version DESC) AS row_num
FROM TEST_RESULT
GROUP BY test_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions.  The key is to put test results with values before the `NULL` values:

```
SELECT tr.*
FROM (SELECT tr.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY test_Id ORDER BY (case when test_result IS NOT NULL then 1 else 2 end), version DESC) AS seqnum
      FROM TEST_RESULT tr
     ) tr
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Note that this returns all `test_Id`s in the table, even those where all results are `NULL`.

Comment: This one returns an error - Could not execute 'SELECT tr.* FROM (SELECT tr.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY test_Id ORDER BY (test_result IS NOT ...'
SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "IS": line 3 col 76 (at pos 109). I changed the `ORDER BY` part to `ORDER BY test_result DESC NULLS LAST, version DESC` and then it executed successfully.

Comment: And wouldn't this return invalid result when for example for `test_id = 60` second test would be `fail` instead of `null`. Because if it orders by `test_result` first then `unprocessable` would be first, no?

Comment: @ReinisVerbelis . . . I fixed the code so it should work with Hana.  And the ordering is by whether or not `test_result` is `null`, not by the value itself.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just exclude the records with `WHERE test_result is NOT NULL`.

```
SELECT test_id, test_result
FROM (
    SELECT 
        test_id,
        test_result,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY test_id ORDER BY version DESC) AS row_num
    FROM TEST_RESULT
    WHERE test_result is NOT NULL
)   
WHERE row_num = 1
```

Comment: . . With this approach, tests with only `NULL` values will not be in the result set.  It is unclear whether that is what the OP wants or not.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, `NULL` can be left out so this works. I don't know why I couldn't approach it this simply.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the best solution but it works :-)

```
WITH T as (
    SELECT test_id,
           max(version) OVER (PARTITION BY test_id ORDER BY version DESC) as version
    FROM test_truc
    WHERE test_result IS NOT NULL 
        OR test_result='fail'
    GROUP BY test_id,
             version)
SELECT DISTINCT T.*,
       test.test_result
FROM T
JOIN test_truc test ON test.version = T.version 
    AND test.test_id = T.test_id
```